# How to make atom the default program when opening .cpp files?

Tags: default, ubuntu-16.04

I just started using ubuntu 16.04 and I want to make atom my default program when working with .cpp files but I don't know how to yet. For example when I click on a .cpp file in one of my folders I want it to open with atom instead of with gedit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open any directory with the file type .cpp in the file explorer, right click on the file and go to properties, there you will find a tab open with. In that tab choose the application you want to open that type of files and hit "Set as Default".